# How to remove alt attribute of img tag in HTML Purifier?

Tags: htmlpurifier

By default, HTML Purifier adds an `alt` attribute to each `img` tag (really annoying behavior). So

```
<img src="123.jpg" />
```

becomes

```
<img src="123.jpg" alt="123.jpg" />
```

Documentation mentiones an [Attr.DefaultImageAlt](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Attr.DefaultImageAlt) option. It defaults to NULL meaning to use the basename of the `src` attribute for the `alt`. When I set `Attr.DefaultImageAlt` to an empty string the result becomes

```
<img src="123.jpg" alt="" />
```

Anyone can suggest how to get rid of the `alt` attribute completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing stems from that the `alt` attribute is mandatory for `img` tags according to the standards, and HTML Purifier takes the standards into account.

That means HTML Purifier, unless you tweak its fundamental HTML handling behaviour (be it by patching HTML Purifier, or by overriding its understanding of certain tags or attributes), cannot be made to leave away the `alt=` attribute.

(Browsers actually have a similar behaviour, though it may not be as apparent - if you remove `alt=`, they will still have an internal `alt=` value that they use instead.)

If this information doesn't change your opinion on how to handle the attribute, read on:

### Patching

*(i.e. changing the behaviour **by** changing the HTML Purifier source code.)*

If you want to patch HTML Purifier to allow `alt` to be absent, you should patch **library/HTMLPurifier/AttrTransform/ImgRequired.php**. You can also see how the `Attr.DefaultImageAlt` directive is used there - if you supply a value of `null` (rather than an empty string), part of the filename will be used as the `alt` value.

### Overriding

*(i.e. changing the behaviour **without** changing the HTML Purifier source code.)*

If you want to override the HTML Purifier behaviour, check out the [Customize!](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) documentation on the HTML Purifier site.

Without having tested it, I believe you need to make two changes to override the behaviour you see:

**1)** Make `alt` non-mandatory:

```
$htmlDef = $this->configuration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$htmlDef->addAttribute('img', 'alt', new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text());
```

The lack of `*` should help you there.

**2)** Remove or replace the `ImgRequired` attribute-transformation.

You can see that the `HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_ImgRequired` class ends up getting registered to both `$htmlDef->info_attr_transform_post['img']` and `$htmlDef->info_attr_transform_pre['img']` in **library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLModule/Image.php**. You *should* be able to do something like this:

```
$htmlDef->info_attr_transform_pre['img'] = array();
$htmlDef->info_attr_transform_post['img'] = array();

// You can *replace* the old behaviour with your own by writing
// your own class and loading it here:
// $htmlDef->info_attr_transform_pre['img'][] = new YourOwnClass();
// $htmlDef->info_attr_transform_post['img'][] = new YourOwnClass();
```

There may be some roadblocks on the way to getting this to work (e.g. the class may be registered somewhere subtly different that I just said it would be - it's been a few years since I tinkered with HTML Purifier on this level!), but this should set you on a good path to getting your hands dirty on HTML Purifier code. :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I made a decision to keep the `alt` attribute since it's mandatory by the standards. I will leave it the way HTML Purifier sets it by default.